# 403 Forbidden from pwa/_api/contextinfo in cordova

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can anyone help me with this error?

I have an application in cordova that can authenticate to the SharePoint Online and even consume OData. But to consume a REST API to run an update needs RequestDigest, there begins my problems. I can not do a post to '/ _api / contextinfo'.

```
$.support.cors = true; // enable cross-domain query
$.ajax({
type: ‘POST’,
data: oAuth.SecurityToken,
crossDomain: true, // had no effect, see support.cors above
contentType: ‘text/xml; charset=”utf-8″‘,
url: oAuth.ProjectURL + ‘/_api/contextinfo’,
dataType: ‘xml’,
success: function (data, textStatus, result) {
var teste = result;

//digest = $(result.responseText).find(“d\\:FormDigestValue”).text();

},
error: function (result, textStatus, errorThrown) {
var response = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
if ((response.error != undefined) && (response.error.message != undefined)) {
alert(response.error.message.value);
}
}
});
```

[image]